# Is it possible to convert string to type in Scala reflection?

Tags: string, scala, reflection, types

I want to convert string to type in scala.Take two following cases as an example:

```
case class Product(id: String, title: String, description: String)
type aType = Product
client.getProduct[aType](id, "/products").map { x => println(s"Retrieved Product with id '$id': $x") } // Working 
// Retrieved Product with id 'test_id': Some(Product(test_id,MyTitle,The text of my Product))

case class Store(id: String, title: String, Address: String)
type aType = Store
client.getStore[aType](id, "/stores").map { x => println(s"Retrieved Store with id '$id': $x") } // working
// Retrieved Store with id 'test_id': Some(Store(test_id, Store Name,The address of my Store))
```

I want to make this code general for any request, given case classes are already defined. for example

```
case class Product(id: String, title: String, description: String)
case class Store(id: String, title: String, Address: String)
case class API_Detail(Name: String, CaseClassName: String, Api_Url:String)
var API_List = List[API_DS]()

val request_type = "Product" // or "Store"
val id = "test_id"

val API_List_Item = API_List.filter(_.Name == request_type)
// Want to do like this...
type aType = API_List_Item.CaseClassName.toType /**/
val RequestURL = API_List_Item.Api_Url
/* Interested to know how to convert string to type. To my knowledge
   some form of reflection will be implemented. */

client.getRespone[aType](id, RequestURL).map { x => println(s"Retrieved $request_type with id '$id': $x") } // Working 
// Retrieved Product with id 'test_id': Some(Product(test_id,MyTitle,The text of my Product))
```

Comment: Here Product is case class.

    case class Product(id: String, title: String, description: String)

Comment: I don't think this is possible as is, but show us greater context and we might be able to solve it. For example how `response` is supposed to be used further? Who this code is expected to be called? Do you expect to be able to access `response.id` (and other fields)? If so, how the compiler might be sure (at the compile time) that the type of `response` is `Product` while you want to provide the actual type only at runtime?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to elaborate my requirement but failed due to the limit of 255 characters.
I have created a new question at the following link. Kindly look at it and help me out. Thanks in advance.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746027/how-to-convert-string-to-type-in-scala-or-any-good-alternate-with-following-cod

Comment: Waqas, you, as the author of the question. can edit it to provide more details. You don't have to create a new question after every worthwhile comment :).

Comment: Thank you SergGr. I have updated my requirement.

Comment: Waqas, sorry but I don't think you address the most important questions: how this imaginary code is supposed to work in a larger context? Imagine you develop the Scala compiler. How your compiler could know at **_compile time_** that  the result of particular call to `client.getResponse` would actually be of type `Product` and thus will have `id` and other fields? Statically typed languages just don't work that way. Still you might be interested in reading ["`TypeTag`s and `Manifest`s"](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for inviting me to this thread. Perhaps you can keep the solution simple enough by using pattern matching. The other solution using implicit class is also valid.

```
val requestUrl = "/products"
requestUrl match {
 case "/products" => Products(...)
 case "/store" => Store(...)
 case _ => UnknownType
}
```

For additional examples on Pattern Matching, see my tutorial at [allaboutscala.com](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-2-learning-basics-scala-programming/scala-tutorial-learn-how-to-use-pattern-matching/)

Comment: The problem here is the `match` statement return type. `Product` and `Store`, as defined in the question, are unrelated types so the statement return type is basically meaningless. You'd have to cast it, or re-pattern match against it, to get a useful `Product` or `Store` out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm extending my previous answer on Pattern Matching. There is no need to re-pattern match if we have a [Polymorphic Function](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html) and I'm making use of [Type Classes](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses.html). I also provide detailed tutorials at [allaboutscala.com](http://allaboutscala.com) on the building blocks for type classes: traits, implicits and functions in general.

You will need to expand getResponse(...) to build and populate the fields for your concrete types.

```
  case class Product(id: String, title: String, description: String)
  case class Store(id: String, title: String, address: String)

  trait Client[T] {
    def getResponse(s: String): Option[T]
  }

  object Client {
    implicit val productClient: Client[Product] = new Client[Product] {
      override def getResponse(s: String): Option[Product] = s match {
        case "/product" => Some(Product("id", "title", "description"))
        case _ => None
     }
  }

   implicit val storeClient: Client[Store] = new Client[Store] {
     override def getResponse(s: String): Option[Store] = s match {
       case "/store" => Some(Store("id", "title", "address"))
       case _ => None
     }
  }

  def apply[T : Client](s: String): Option[T] = 
    implicitly[Client[T]].getResponse(s)
  }

val product: Option[Product] = Client[Product]("/product")
val store: Option[Store] = Client[Store]("/store")
```